# Spawn hector quadrotor in custom gazebo world

Tags: ros, gazebo-4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created a custom world using model editor in gazebo4, as shown below.

[image: image description]

I was trying to run a fun project where I can fly the quadrotor model through the rings, using vision based algorithm and solution. Thus, I came across hector quadrotor and wanted to use the robot model in this world.

This command can spawn the quadrotor into an empty world

```
    roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

but this requires to have gazebo_ros. and that would remove gazebo4 and this world I created. Can I spawn the hector quadrotor directly into this world of gazebo4?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9388/spawn-hector-quadrotor-in-custom-gazebo-world./) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sure you can. I did exactly this with lots of worlds by just creating a catkin package called `quad_world` with a launch file in it that spawns the quadcopter and all kinds of other stuff (I used `quadrotor_empty_world.launch` as base).

As follows:
`start.launch` contains:

```
<arg name="world_name" default="$(find quad_world)/worlds/tonystart124.world" />
<include file="$(find quad_world)/launch/world.launch">
  <arg name="world_name" default="$(arg world_name)"/>
</include>

<include file="$(find hector_quadrotor_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor.launch" />
```

`world.launch` is the following:

```
  <!-- these are the arguments you can pass this launch file, for example paused:=true -->
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="verbose" default="false" />

  <arg name="world_name" />

  <!-- set use_sim_time flag -->
  <group if="$(arg use_sim_time)">
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </group>

  <!-- set command arguments -->
  <arg unless="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg paused)" name="command_arg1" value="-u"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg headless)" name="command_arg2" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg headless)" name="command_arg2" value="-r"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value=""/>
  <arg     if="$(arg verbose)" name="command_arg3" value="--verbose"/>
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="gzserver"/>
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="script_type" value="debug"/>

  <!-- start gazebo server-->
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="$(arg script_type)" respawn="false" output="screen"
    args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) $(arg world_name)" />
    
  <!-- start gazebo client -->
  <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gzclient" respawn="false" output="screen"/>


</launch>
```

Good luck with your project!

---

Originally posted by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) with karma: 96 on 2015-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-13**:
thanks a lot for your answer. am considerably new to ROS and Gazebo. Could you please tell me how I should go about using these launch files? The world file I have saved is as ".sdf".

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-13**:
should I save my world as .world?

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2015-09-13**:
sorry for anotherquestion, but is gazeo_ros required for this?

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) on 2015-09-14**:
Yes and yes. Save it as .world instead of .sdf and if you look at the last command of world.launch you see the node `gazebo_ros` is started.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try installing `ros-indigo-gazebo4-ros-pkgs`, since it sounds like you have already followed the instructions on [getting packages from packages.osrfoundation.org](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=4.0#Step-by-stepInstall).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1